# Rendering grails views on different sub URL

Tags: grails

I am creating a rest based web application. i want all the rest based pages (HTML pages) should go into webapps folder and should be accessible at from there with the below URL 
http://localhost:8080/myapp.

Above URL should render index.html lying in webapps folder. And all the subsequent pages should open from webapps folder only.

For the admin part i want to use grails views(GSP) and they should be accessible at 
http://localhost:8080/myapp/admin

Above url should render the index.gsp page lying in grails-app/views/index.gsp.

To list all users on admin site, i want URL to be some thing like this
http://localhost:8080/myapp/admin/user/list and this should point to grails-app/views/user/list.gsp and userController with action list

Is there a way this can be achieved in Grails

Comment: What version of grails are you using? "Rest based pages" means html pages with js inside? What is the structure of your pages under _/myapp_ url? Do you have any controller for the "admin part", or are you using gsp pages only for basic templating? Please add more and specific information to you question. By now is too generic.

Comment: Grails Version : 2.5.1
Yes rest based pages means html pages with JS inside.
 I do have controllers for admin part
Like For domain User, i have UserController and its corresponding views in grails-app/views/user/...
I want this page to viewed at https://localhost:8080/myapp/admin/user/...

Basically I want all my grails views (GSP's) to be accessed at /myapp/admin 
and all other pages (present in webapps) and rest api's at http://localhost:8080/myapp/

Answer (score 1):

Grails exposes your controllers and views using conventions by default. However, if you want to break that convention you can. There is nothing stopping you from re-working how the URL mappings are done in your application. In fact there is an [entire section of the documentation](http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.4.x/guide/theWebLayer.html#urlmappings) dedicated to it.

Let's pretend for a second you wanted all your controllers to be under `/admin/` you could easily change your `UrlMappings.groovy` to look like this:

```
class UrlMappings {
    static mappings = {
    "/admin/$controller/$action?/$id?(.$format)?"{
            constraints {
                // apply constraints here
            }
        }
}
```

Once you read through the documentation you should be able to map things however you want. The key is you have to define how you want them mapped.